# Is there a way to add a form to a mdi form from a form which is inside it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add a form to my mdi-container **from a form which is already added to it** but it is not possible (i do not mean showing a form i mean adding it to the mdi-container)
Do you know how is it possible?
thanks

Comment: Should be possible if you have a reference to the parent container. Can you show some code?

Comment: hi, I made a public method in the mdi-container form and i tried to call it from the other form it does not show any error but it also does not add the new form to the mdi-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do something like this:

```
// Button on MDI child.
private void AddFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newChildForm = new SomeForm();
    newChildForm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    newChildForm.Show();
}
```